# Why Contacts are not load in My Application with iOS 9?

Tags: ios, addressbook, ios9

i am using this code for get all contact from address book but i face issue with iOS 9 i cant find solution for that if anyone know about that please help me.

```
-(void)getContactsFromAddressBook
    {
        CFErrorRef error = NULL;
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        if (addressBook) {
            NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
            NSUInteger i = 0;
            self.arrContact = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            self.arrOnlyNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (i = 0; i<[allContacts count]; i++)  {
                addressContact *addressObj = [[addressContact alloc] init];
                ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
                // Get first and last names
                NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                NSString *lastName= (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
                if(!firstName) {
                    firstName = kEMPTY_STRING;
                }
                if (!lastName) {
                    lastName=kEMPTY_STRING;
                }
                addressObj.strFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                CFDataRef imgData = ABPersonCopyImageData(contactPerson);
                NSData *imageData = (__bridge NSData *)imgData;
                addressObj.imgProfile = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                // Get mobile number
                ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                if ([self getMobilePhoneProperty:phonesRef]!=nil) {
                    addressObj.strPhonNo = [self getMobilePhoneProperty:phonesRef];
                    NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
                    addressObj.strPhonNo = [[addressObj.strPhonNo componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:kEMPTY_STRING];
                    addressObj.strPhonNo = [addressObj.strPhonNo substringFromIndex: [addressObj.strPhonNo length] - 10];

                    [self.arrOnlyNumber addObject:addressObj.strPhonNo];

                    if ([firstName isEqualToString:@""] && [lastName isEqualToString:@""]) {
                        addressObj.strFullName = addressObj.strPhonNo;
                    }
                    [self.arrContact addObject:addressObj];
                }
                if(phonesRef) {
                    CFRelease(phonesRef);
                }
            }

            self.contactViewObj.arrContact = self.arrContact;
            //[self.contactViewObj viewWillAppear:YES];
            if (self.arrContact.count == 0) {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:kALERT_MESAGE_TITLE message:kALERT_MESSAGE delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:kALERT_OK, nil]show];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
    }

- (NSString *)getMobilePhoneProperty:(ABMultiValueRef)phonesRef {
    for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phonesRef); i++) {
        CFStringRef currentPhoneLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phonesRef, 0);
        CFStringRef currentPhoneValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, 0);
        if(currentPhoneLabel) {
            if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
                return (__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue;
            }
            if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABHomeLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
                return (__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue;
            }
        }
        if(currentPhoneLabel) {
            CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel);
        }
        if(currentPhoneValue) {
            CFRelease(currentPhoneValue);
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I tried for around a full day, but no luck yet.
Please provide me any help or any direction regarding this issue.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Post your code, without it we will not be able to tell what is going on.

Comment: i have this code. for load contact.

Comment: Where is the code failing?  Do you expect us to debug all of that code?